# auto run application

Tags: windows, winforms, authentication

I published my windows application and I burn it in my CD and I added autorun.inf file for running this cd with autoplay but it did not run so I could not solve this problem

```
autorun.inf

[autorun]     
open=setup.exe
icon=Nero.ico
```

Comment: See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/330135 for autorun troubleshooting tips

Comment: See also http://support.microsoft.com/kb/967715 for lots of information on the disabling of autorun

Answer (score 0):

Maybe auto-run of CD's is disabled on the computer you tried it?

Comment: Isn't autorun for CD/USB disabled by a recent Windows update?